# Regular expression not matching float value

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for these 2 lines of String

```
txt="[0, 0, 1.8, 1.0] value = 9.99999986991104E14";
txt="[0, 0, 1, 1] value = 9.99999986991104E14";

String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re2="\\d+";  // Uninteresting: int
String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re4="\\d+";  // Uninteresting: int
/*
* x 3rd value
*/
String re5=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re6="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
/*
* y 4 th value
*/
String re7=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re8="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 2
/*
* value
*/
String re9=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re10="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])"; // Float 1
String re11="((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))"; // Alphanum 1

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);

if (m.find())
{
    String x = m.group(1);
    String y = m.group(2);
    String value = m.group(3)+m.group(4);
    System.out.print("x "+x.toString()+" y "+y.toString()+" value"+value.toString()+"\n");
}
```

These regular expressions give me the the following result

```
case 1: x 1 y 8 value9.99999986991104E14
Case 2: x 1 y 1 value9.99999986991104E14
```

However, I had expected the results to be (case 1)

```
 Case 1: x 1.8 y 1.0 value9.99999986991104E14
 Case 2: x 1 y 1 value9.99999986991104E14
```

for x,y and value. I need to match both the integer and the float value.

Am I doing anything wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: This isn't clear.  What results were you expecting?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: update question

Comment: I am trying to get  Case 1: x 1.8 y 1.0 value9.99999986991104E14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the values for `re6` and `re8`, you are only looking at non decimal values (the dot is not included).

I suggest including the dot with the following changes

```
String re6 = "([.\\d]+)";
```

and

```
String re8 = "([.\\d]+)";
```

*Edit* for addition on the "value" part:

For the last Group, where you are trying to get number string, I would do it like this:

```
String re10 = "value ="; // Searching for fixed String value
String re11 = "[ ]*"; // Looking for whitespaces
String re12 = "([.E\\d]+)";// Looking for A String containing: Numbers/Dots/Letter-E at with at least one match
```

One Group to match both cases: Including E or not, Containing dot or not. - Since the value String is fixed, I included it in the regex.

Comment: No need to escape the dot inside the character class.

Comment: @KnusperPudding : thanks now it prints float and integer values aswell. Should I include the same in value regex? As if value is integer and if it doesnot contain E, then it is not working. I should take values if it is integeror float or if it doesnot contain E

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni I would say, it depends on how flexible your result is: is there always the String "value = " ? and what might be possible variations of the number String at the end?

Comment: @KnusperPudding: Yes there wil be always value=,but the calues can contain in,float,with E,without E

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni i updated my answer with an approach on how this could work.

Comment: @KnusperPudding: replace the last ggroup with what you have suggested right?Once doing that it is not giving any result

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni yeah, replacing `re10` and `re11`, also adding `re12`. so the 'full' regex would look like this: .*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?([\\.\\d]+).*?(\\d+).*?value =[ ]*([.E\\d]+)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84441/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-knusperpudding).